# Some Keyboard shortcut doesn't work

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Loki and when I try to move a window from a desktop to another this doesn't work. Or better It's move to the left but not to the right. I've tried to reassign the shortcuts but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

go to System setting->keyboard->shortcuts  click on any function on the right box and choose what shortcut u want to use for that function.